# Get into bluetooth receive mode by codeline

Tags: windows, vb.net, shell, command-line, bluetooth

I receive several files from smartphones everyday.
Now I perform this, setting the PC in "receive file" mode from the bluetooth icon menu on the taskbar (right click -> Receive file) and then confirm where to save the file. But I have to open by hand several instances of that receive-files subprogram every day.

How to get into this receive-files window by command line? or where is located?

(then with this "shortcut" I could program an automated opening of multiple instances!)

BT program is called  fsquirt.exe
but this main bluetooth interface offers receive and send options. Is there an option to get into specific receive subroutine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i found  this is:

fsquirt.exe -receive

another argument could be

fsquirt.exe -send